# Which approach is recommended for EEG-Signal Classification

Tags: classification, biostatistics, bioinformatics

I am given a dataset of EEG Signal of a rat and a system of classes proposed by neuroscientists. The dataset is unprocessed. 
I dont know which approach is appropiate. Beeing inspired by speech processing, i have thought of using markov models paired with gaussian mixtures. An advice would be much appreciated